# Efficient way to query instead of multiple OR

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am trying make a query a bit more efficent than what I have now. There is a column that has 16 different values that I want to use, it has many more. Instead of using column = value1 OR column = value2, etc. all the way to up 16, is there a better way to do it?

Below is an example of what I'm working with, and what I'm trying to do.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE A.COLUMN1 = VALUE1
OR A.COLUMN1 = VALUE2
OR A.COLUMN1 = VALUE5
OR A.COLUMN1 = VALUE7
etc..
```

What I would prefer to do is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE A.COLUMN1 = {VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE5, VALUE7, etc.}
```

Thanks

Comment: are the values you're looking up in a different table that you could somehow limit and then join on?  Say you and a table of last names and you wanted all names like 'S%' you could join table_A back to the names table limiting on 'S%' and thereby getting records in that set of data.

Comment: You could use `IN` operator but I suggest use `JOIN`

Comment: The column is just single characters, I don't think there is really a good way to filter the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [an `IN` condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions013.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE A.COLUMN1 IN (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE5, VALUE7);
```

It won't be any more efficient in operation as it will be transformed back into `OR` statements by the database engine, but it's arguably more efficient to write and maintain.

You also have a limit of 1000 items in the list, but if you're getting anywhere near that (and obviously you are not, with just 16) then another approach is usually better anyway.

You should consider where your 16 values are coming from though; if they are ultimately from another table then you should probably rework this to do a join, or possibly a subquery.

---

These are not equivalent:

```
<something> AND M.PRODUCT_CODE IN ('A','J')
```

and

```
<something> AND M.PRODUCT_CODE = 'A' OR M.PRODUCT_CODE = 'J'
```

The second one would be evaulated as:

```
(<something> AND M.PRODUCT_CODE = 'A') OR M.PRODUCT_CODE = 'J'
```

So you will get results from that for any row with `PRODUCT_CODE = 'J'`, even if the other conditions are not net. [Logic condition precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#sthref1905) is important:

> Oracle evaluates conditions with equal precedence from left to right within an expression, with the following exceptions:
>
> - Left to right evaluation is not guaranteed for multiple conditions connected using AND.
> - Left to right evaluation is not guaranteed for multiple conditions connected using OR.

You should use parentheses to avoid ambiguity - even if it is doing what you want, explicitly using them makes your intent clear, and makes it easier to modify the code later without nasty side-effects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am not getting the correct result by using IN though. I'll update the question

Comment: @user3661576 - that looks more like your `OR` version is giving incorrect results, due to the lack of parentheses - you need to look at [the precedence of the logical operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#sthref1905). Does `a AND b OR c` mean `(a AND b) OR c`, or does it mean `a AND (b OR c)` ...?

Comment: Thanks, my brain is fried right now. In the example above I was using the values I didn't want to include... It is working as intended now, appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE A.COLUMN1 IN {VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE5, VALUE7}
```

Comment: Please add some comment so that it is helpful to OP